# how to close a tabbed window using testcomplete?

Tags: winforms, vbscript, devexpress, testcomplete

I am trying to access a tabbed window which is under Multiple Document interface window under which there are tabs which are generated dynamically.
I wanted to check whether the new  tab is opened successfully or not, and after its been opened i need to close it too.I tried to get the number of tabs opened using the following piece of code:

```
mdiclient.ChildCount
```

Now need a way to close the opened Tab without using Click coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the tab object as a child of the **mdiclient** window and then call its **Close** method.

Answer (score 0):

tried using The Close one .. but it always closed the 1st tab .. so i found a Workaround,
use :

```
mdiclient.Child(index).Dispose
```

Worked for me like a charm... got the count of the number of tabs opened using the

```
mdiclient.Controls.get_count
```